# How can Rails have different csrf tokens at different times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, csrf

#### tl;dr

In my product, rails seems to have different csrf tokens on different page visits, but I thought that there was only one csrf token per session. Am I misunderstanding how rails' csrf token works? or is it something with my situation?

Some contextual information: The website is actually a war running within tomcat. Part of the code runs on rails via [jruby-rack](https://github.com/jruby/jruby-rack) (please don't ask why ;) it's what I've got).

#### details

For a situation I'm in, I manually added debugging code in rail's csrf code. Specifically I changed the [`verified_request? method`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L186) to be this:

```
  def verified_request?
    logger.info "printing info from `verified_request?` ..."
    logger.info "\trequest_forgery_protection_token = #{request_forgery_protection_token}"
    logger.info "\tform_authenticity_token = #{form_authenticity_token}"
    logger.info "\tparams[request_forgery_protection_token] = #{params[request_forgery_protection_token]}"
    logger.info "\trequest.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] = #{request.headers['X-CSRF-Token']}"
    logger.info
    !protect_against_forgery? || request.get? ||
      form_authenticity_token == params[request_forgery_protection_token] ||
      form_authenticity_token == request.headers['X-CSRF-Token']
  end
```

Below is the log output. The important part is that the 'form_authenticity_token' is *different* at different times (but it does repeat itself at times). That doesn't make sense to me because the [`form_authenticity_token` function](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L193) returns the same thing for every single session.

```
printing info from `verified_request?` ...
    request_forgery_protection_token = authenticity_token
    form_authenticity_token = wMPfNOM8s1Z0tLfeDJRpwKoWYGnA/K21SkgROLP2DMY=
    params[request_forgery_protection_token] = 
    request.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] = 

printing info from `verified_request?` ...
    request_forgery_protection_token = authenticity_token
    form_authenticity_token = viGS5kkOGvte7Sq+FpRsowiwujJNG8Y2WpTqqEShCy0=
    params[request_forgery_protection_token] = 
    request.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] = 

printing info from `verified_request?` ...
    request_forgery_protection_token = authenticity_token
    form_authenticity_token = lBpCrPHpuyyiyfCs30Jonz+vqOsQG1VKbbPOJl07DNE=
    params[request_forgery_protection_token] = 
    request.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] = viGS5kkOGvte7Sq+FpRsowiwujJNG8Y2WpTqqEShCy0=

printing info from `verified_request?` ...
    request_forgery_protection_token = authenticity_token
    form_authenticity_token = wMPfNOM8s1Z0tLfeDJRpwKoWYGnA/K21SkgROLP2DMY=
    params[request_forgery_protection_token] = viGS5kkOGvte7Sq+FpRsowiwujJNG8Y2WpTqqEShCy0=
    request.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] =
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that we were running multiple processes of jruby *and* were using memory for caching. This meant that each process had a different session. We returned to only having one process of jruby.